# Linear search Algo (Bug)

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

**I need help here I want to fix this code so it print (Target is found at:) just if it found the target, insted of printing the word even if it dosn't found the target**

*for example if the user want to find number 3 in array of {1, 2, 3, 4, 3} it should print*
**Target is found at index: 2, 4**

*but if the user want for exmaple to find 2 in array of {1, 3, 4, 5} it should print*
**Not Found**

```
#include <stdio.h>


void search(int array[], int n, int k);

#define MAX 100

int main(void)
{
    int array[MAX];
    int n;
    int k;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Initial array:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Target element: %d\n", k);

    printf("Target is found at: ");
    search(array, n, k);

    //(result == -1) ? printf("No target\n") : printf("Target is found at: %d\n", result);
}

void search(int array[], int n, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (k == array[i])
            printf("%d ", i);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you want this program to do and what it currently does?

Answer (score 0):

remove the line where you print that message:

```
printf("Target is found at: ");
```

and if you find the value...

```
printf("Target is found at: %d\n", i);
```

you could also add a return statement inside the if and a message that the value wasn't found outside the for:

```
 void search(int array[], int n, int k)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (k == array[i])
        {
           printf("Target is found at: %d\n", i);
           return;
         }
     printf("value not found\n");
 }
```

Comment: This won't produce the desired "Target is found at index: 2, 4" mentioned in the question.